# Accessing all function argmuments

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I have a function with 4 arguments and want to check those 4 arguments for something.
Currently I do it like this:

```
def function1(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    arg1 = function2(arg1)
    arg2 = function2(arg2)
    arg3 = function2(arg3)
    arg4 = function2(arg4)

def function2(arg):
    arg = dosomething(arg)
    return arg
```

I think this is not really a nice way to do it, so my idea is to do something like this:

```
def function1(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    for arg in listOfArguments:
        arg = function2(arg)


def function2(arg):
    arg = checkSomething(arg)
    return arg
```

Is there a way in Python to get a list of all the arguments passed to `function1`?

Thanks for your help and ideas.

Comment: There is: `*args` for arbitrary argument lists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have a *set* number of arguments *just create an iterable out of them*, for example, wrap the argument names in a tuple literal:

```
for arg in (arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    # do stuff
```

If you don't mind your function being capable of being called with more args just use [`*args` syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

```
def function1(*args):
    for arg in args:
        arg = function2(arg)
```

which then exposes the arguments with which the function was invoked as a tuple which can be iterated over.

If you need to store the results for every invocation, it is better to change the `for-loop` in a [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) creating a list of the returned values. For example, given a function that takes a value and simply adds `2` to it:

```
def add2(arg):
    return arg + 2

def function1(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    a1, a2, a3, a4 = [add2(arg) for arg in (arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)]
    print(a1, a2, a3, a4)
```

We create a list comprehension that takes every `arg` and supplies it to `add2` and then stores it as an entry in a list, then we unpack to `a1,..,aN`. The values now contain the results of the function calls:

```
function1(1, 2, 3, 4)
3, 4, 5, 6
```

In the previous examples `(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)` can always be replaced with `args` if you use the `*args` syntax when defining the function, the results will be similar.

---

As an addendum, if you're more a fan of functional programming, you could always **[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)** the arguments to the function and save a few characters :-). I'll add a `*args` definition of `function1` this time:

```
def function1(*args):
    a1, a2, a3, a4 = map(add2, args)
    print(a1, a2, a3, a4)
```

Same result.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. There is now the problem, that arg = function2(arg) is creating a new value for arg, but this value is lost after the for-loop is finished. How to pass the new value of arg back to my args so i can work with them after the for-loop is done?

Comment: I've edited my answer, if you need to store the returned value you can just use a list-comprehension instead of a `for` loop. Then unpack the resulting list to variables you can work with, i.e `a1, a2, a3, a4 = r`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use `*args`:

```
In [1]: def func(*args):
   ...:     print(len(args), args)
   ...:     

In [2]: func(1, 2, 3, 4)
4 (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

More information can be found [here.](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/)

Comment: Print is a function in py3

Comment: @Sevanteri: fixed